# Cannot assign to Func<Interface> from Func<T>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

If I have

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Func<IModel> InputFunc { get; set; }
}
```

and try to do

```
public void SetInput<TInput>(Func<TInput> funcInput) where TInput:IModel
{
   ...
   var c = new MyClass();
   c.InputFunc = funcInput;
   ...
}
```

I get a compile-error

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<TInput>' to 'System.Func<IModel>'
```

Why is this caused?
How can I overcome this issue? 
(I tried the where clause but is not helping)

Comment: This should be fine in C#4 on .net 4. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hmm it doesn't compile for some reason in C# 4.

Comment: I am using C#4 on Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I thought so too, but there's a tweak required on the generic type parameter constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You're probably using C# 3 / .NET 3.5 (or earlier).

   Generic covariance for interfaces and delegates was only introduced in C# 4.
2. It's just because you haven't required that `TInput` is a reference type. Try this:

   ```
   void SetInput<TInput>(Func<TInput> func) where TInput : class, IModel
   ```

   This is required because otherwise `TInput` could be a *value type* implementing `IModel` (I'm assuming `IModel` is an interface) and covariance isn't supported for value types (due to representation differences).

I've just tried it with the extra constraint, and it's fine in C# 4.

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, IModel was an interface and the tweak worked nice. Thank you.